# Can't find Developer Options on Android Virtual Device running Android 8.0.0 (Oreo)

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-8.0-oreo

I can't find Developer Options in Virtual Device running Android 8.0.0 (Oreo)

[image: Emulator View]

Comment: Please explain, why it's being downvoted?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Open `Settings -> System -> About Emulated Device`
2. Keep tapping on `Build number` multiple times.

Only then you will get access to `Developer Options`

Comment: After that what should i do

Comment: This is to enable `Developer Options`. Now if you search for `Developer Options` again, you will find that option.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and after some google troubleshooting I found it.
Hope that it will help you as well:

You can find it here: Settings->System->Advance

[image]

[image]

[image]
And yes is for AVD devices :)